# Value not showing after page refresh

Tags: jquery

I have an "input-range" and the value is directly shown in a "span" when I move it. The problem is when I put a default value on the "input" the "span" doesn't update until I move my mouse on it. How can I make it so it updates the "span" automatically without touching anything ?

```
<input type="range" value="60" min="0" max="180" step="15" name="angle">
<span>0°</span>

$(function() {
    $('input[type=range]').on('mousemove', function() {
        $('span').html(this.value + '°');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vb36aL0y/21/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$(function() {
    $('span').html($('input[type=range]').val() + '°');
    $('input[type=range]').on('mousemove', function() {
        $('span').html(this.value + '°');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to set the initial value 60 on initial view.. Try this,

```
$(function() {
    var rangeInput = $('input[type=range]');
    $('span').html(rangeInput.val() + '°');
    rangeInput.on('mousemove', function() {
        $('span').html(this.value + '°');
    });
});
```

Comment: Do take time to read other answers before you post a answer. Try not to repeat the same answer.

Comment: I was trying the code in fiddler and while clicking back button in browser, some how missed it.